# Dependence on External Maven and Git Resources

Tags: spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-dataflow

Application information:

- Spring Cloud Data Flow Server Cloudfoundry 1.0.0.RELEASE (DIY built with Spring Cloud Config Server dependencies)
- Spring Cloud Config Server
- PCF Elastic Runtime 1.7.x

I'm curious about the extent to which applications and the deployer depend on the Git repo and Maven artifact repository I'm binding my SCDF instance and my Spring Cloud Config Server instance to in PCF.

My suspicion is that the Maven repo is only used at deployment time, when an artifact needs to be downloaded for installation and deployment in the PCF space.  Also, I'm thinking the Git repo is probably cloned by the Config Server whenever an application initialization, or refresh event occurs that would require the need to re-read the configuration information stored in Git.

Is this true, or are there ongoing dependencies that would require high availability for these external resources?  My question is related to disaster recover planning activities, and how quickly these specific resources need to be recovered for Spring Cloud Data Flow and its deployed streams to continue working under adverse conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My suspicion is that the Maven repo is only used at deployment time, when an artifact needs to be downloaded for installation and deployment in the PCF space.

Yes - The applications are resolved and downloaded upon stream deployment request and the resolved apps are cached and reused upon redeployments.

> I'm thinking the Git repo is probably cloned by the Config Server whenever an application initialization

True - For a given URI of a configuration source, the server will clone the repository and make its configurations available to all the client applications bound to it.

These two capabilities are driven by application bootstrap event. As for the `config-server`, if you're running it as a service in Cloud Foundry, it's up to the platform to reliably serve the properties to the bound applications.